# Trying to send emails using Django OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: django, smtp, sendmail

I was trying to send email from gmail account to another using django
as show in images below

**settings.py** file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GXMx.png

then i get this error when i use the **send_mail()**

**OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kISS.png